# Unity 2021.3.0f1 freezing everytime i press run

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, freeze

every time I press run to see if my script is running (it's a simple script all it has is a print function) and unity freezes, I have to close it through task manager.it seemed to start happening when I updated unity hub (to 3.1.1) and updated my project to a new version of unity (to 2021.3.0f1). I tried going back to the previous version of unity, but it didn't work, I also tried restarting my computer and it didn't work either. I tried looking for other solutions on forums but they are all from years ago and didn't work

Comment: Unfortunately there is not enough information provided unless we make guesses.  Either code needs to be shown to us, or logs need to be provided, otherwise we are just making random guesses.

If your script is causing an infinite loop, then this would happen.  Run Unity without any script to verify that it is not a scripting issue.  Please give more information to receive help with this issue.

Comment: @KalibCrone It looks like it was caused by the script! I was practicing while loops by printing things to the console and when i removed it, it stopped freezing, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you may have an infinite loop running, we would need to see the script in question to know for sure. But if that's not the case, you may just need to rebuild your Library.

Comment: Deleting the while loop worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you are not using *wrong while* loops. Even if not & the loop seems correct, comment it & check if you are right.

Comment: Deleting the while loop worked! Thank you!